# Convert nested vector maps in clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to collect and transfer `:c/name` values into nested vector to first level same way.

Input example:

```
[:a/name "name" :a/vals [{:b/val [{:c/name "one"}{:c/name "two"}]}
                         {:b/val [{:c/name "three"}]}]]
```

Output:

```
[:a/name :a/vals "one, two, three"]
```

Comment: That seems like a weird input format for your data. Where is it coming from? Could you make an attempt to solve the problem and show us what you've tried?

Comment: This looks like another attempt at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878126/parse-vector-of-maps-in-clojure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output from the input, is this what you want?

```
(defn f [[k1 _ k2 rels]]
  [k1 k2
   (clojure.string/join ", "
     (map :c/name (apply concat (mapcat vals rels))))])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is what I want! But what changed in code if I want to add some conditions:  [:a/name "name" :a/vals [{:b/val [{:c/name "one" :c/u "1"}{:c/name "two" :c/u "2"}]}
                         {:b/val [{:c/name "three" :c/u "1"}]}]]   And add to result if :c/u = "1" or :c/u is missing

Comment: Yup, you can filter the rels, something like `(filter #(or (not (contains? :c/u %) (= (:c/u %) "1")) rels)`

Comment: Thank you for solution! But could you write whole script with filter, I have some errors to try use this filter in function.

Comment: I tried this way (def res [:a/name "name" :a/vals [{:b/val [{:c/name "one" :c/u "1"}
                                           {:c/name "two" :c/u "2"}]} 
                                  {:b/val [{:c/name "three" :c/u "1"}]}]])

(defn f [[k1 _ k2 rels]] 
  [k1 k2 (clojure.string/join ", " 
                              (map :c/name (apply concat (mapcat vals 
                                      (filter #(or (not (contains? % :c/u)) (= (:c/u %) "1")) rels)))))])
                                    
(prn (f res)) and I get values without filtering [:a/name :a/vals "one, two, three"]

Comment: So.. I expect that only items with :c/u = "1" is filtered, so the result should be following: [:a/name :a/vals "one, three"]

Comment: `(def x
  [:a/name "name" :a/vals
   [{:b/val [{:c/name "one" :c/u "1"} {:c/name "two" :c/u "2"}]} {:b/val [{:c/name "three" :c/u "1"}]}]])
 
(defn pred [m]
  (or (not (contains? m :c/u)) (= (:c/u m) "1")))

(defn g [rels]
   (apply concat (mapcat vals rels)))

(defn f [[k1 _ k2 rels]]
  [k1 k2 (clojure.string/join ", " (map :c/name
                                        (filter pred
                                            (g rels))))]))

(f x)` => [:a/name :a/vals "one, three"]